# How to read every line of a file individually, in order to perform a task on each line? - Scala

Tags: scala, for-loop

My goal is to read a file one line at a time and to separate that particular line by "&"  and then multiply all numbers in that line.

One line in the file will look like this:

```
2&3&5&1
```

There can be any number of numbers per line, and any number of lines like this.

This is what I've tried:

```scala
import scala.io.{BufferedSource, Source}

object Multiply {

  def processFile(fileName: String): Int = {

    val file = Source.fromFile(fileName)
    var product: Int = 1

    for (line <- file.getLines()) {
      val splits = line.split("&")
      for (x <- splits) {
        product *= x.toInt
      }
    }

    product
  }
}
```

This returns the product of the entire file. I need the program to print out the product of each line individually. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The problem is that you re-use `Y` on each line, and only initialize it once. Your function needs to return a `Seq[Int]` (or `List[Int]`) in order to return the product of the values on each line; alternatively it should return `Unit` and print the values out for each line. Your `line` argument should be called `fileName`, and your `numb` variable should be called `line`, `Y` should be `y` (_Scala_ reserves capital case for constants), and `y` should be initialized before the inner loop, not before the outer loop. However, Brian's answer is simpler, functional and correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the nested `for` loops may be your issue. Either way started from scratch with a `for-yield` approach and the more functional `map`. The `toList` is just so it prints on the REPL.

```
scala> file
res25: String =
2&3&5&1
1&1&2&2
42&2&1&1
42&3&1&1

scala> for (line <- file.lines)
     | yield line.split("&").map(_.toInt).product
res26: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> res26.toList
res27: List[Int] = List(30, 4, 84, 126)

scala> file.lines.map(line => line.split("&").map(_.toInt).product).toList
res28: List[Int] = List(30, 4, 84, 126)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to repair it:

```
import scala.io.Source

object Multiply {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // assumes `fileName` is in the first arg
    val fileName = args(0)

    for (line <- Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines()) {
      println(line.split("&").map(_.toInt).product)
    }
  }
}
```

Some hints:

- Don't introduce unnecessary bottlenecks. A function with signature `def processFile(name: String): Int` is mostly useless, because it can neither accept a callback to be invoked on each line, nor does it return a sequence of integers, so it's unsuitable for doing anything *with each line*.
- Instead of mutable `product` accumulator variable, use `reduce` or `foldLeft`. e.g.

  ```
  line.split("&").map(_.toInt).foldLeft(1)(_ * _)
  ```

  would be equivalent to what you did, but fortunately, for this special case, there is a shorter `.product` method for multiplying all numbers in a sequence.
- You can chain multiple method calls, no need to introduce a variable for every intermediate result.
- Compare edit history: adhere to naming conventions, indent your code.